# PyQgis: Extract SVG-Symbols and SVG-Paths of all Layers of my QGIS Project

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, svg

I want to extract the SVG-Paths and SVG-Symbols for all Layers in my QGIS Project.

The purpose is to open the SVG files via a plugin (so via PyQgis) and I don't know how to do so.
I checked the QGIS Pyton API but did not find a solution (have to admit that I'm quite new to PyQgis).

Would be glad if someone could give me a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested in how I fixed my problem:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import json
import os

tree = ET.parse('test_project.qgs')
root = tree.getroot()

svg_list = []
# get the svg-files from the qgs-file 
for svg in root.iter('prop'): 
    prop_dic = svg.attrib
    text = json.dumps(prop_dic)
    if ".svg" not in text:
        continue
    else:
        test = text.split('"')
        matching = [s for s in test if ".svg" in s]
        svg_list.append(str(matching)[2:-2])

#get the registered svg Paths that are deposited under options/system/svg-paths
svg_Path = qgis.core.QgsApplication.svgPaths()

#search for every file in each path
for p in svg_Path:
    for svg in svg_list:
        svg_w = os.path.join(p, svg)
        #check in which path the file is present
        if os.path.exists(svg_w) is True: 
            print('found')
        else:
            pass
```

Im pretty sure it's not the best way to do the task, but it worked for me, so maybe i can help somebody with this.

The code is executed in the QGis Python Console, otherwise more imports are needed.

Answer (score 1):

If an SVG is referenced in your project, it is contained in the project file, usually a file with `.qgz` (compressed) or `.qgs` (not compressed).

By expanding a `.qgz` project file, a `.qgs` file is obtained.

`.qgs` project files are actually standard `.xml` file, so you can open them with any text editor, searching "svg".

Under Linux you can conveniently grep for "svg" instances:

```
> grep svg your_project.qgs
          <prop k="name" v="food/food_bar.svg"/>
          ...
          <prop k="name" v="amenity/amenity_library.svg"/>
>
```

Comment: Got already the Qgs Project File, but need the whole path for the used svg files, since there could be more search paths / svg locations in my options.